# Why is this xpath not working using PhantomJS?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm building a scraper that needs to scrape prices from a dozen of different websites .

All websites use JS to show the price, so I went with selenium in order to scrape the data needed .

Before starting to build the scraper, I created a list of xpaths I need to get the price element for each url I was scraping in an external file .

I got those xpath using FireFox and Firebug, Hoàwever I get an errror, everytime I try to get these element with selenium (PhantomJS driver ):

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Una
ble to find element with xpath './div'","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"applicat
ion/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"89
","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:51048","User
-Agent":"Python-urllib/2.7"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"usin
g\": \"xpath\", \"sessionId\": \"27f41b80-cf63-11e6-bbcc-13b1a315759a\", \"value
\": \"./div\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"ele
ment","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"
","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/
element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/27f41b80-cf
63-11e6-bbcc-13b1a315759a/element"}}
```

It seems that my xpath is wrong, However I double checked it, using other plugins and it's correct everytime I test that xpath on Firefox .

Here are two different xpaths that both should work, (they did using Firfox , but didn't with selenium) :

```
"id('regular-hero')/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/span"

"/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/span/text()[1]"
```

And here's the target page html code [Here](https://jsbin.com/veduleyiqu/edit?html,output)

And here's the code to get the elemnts using selenium :

```
self.browser = wd.PhantomJS()
for n in xrange(len(self.url_list)):
    url = self.url_list[n]
    provider = self.provider_list[n]
    self.browser.get(url)
    for plan in provider:
        for hosting_plan in provider[plan]:
            xpath = hosting_plan.values()[0] # Get the xpath of a plan
            price_elem = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*")
            print price_elem

self.browser.close()
```

All the loops are used to traverse the JSON external file that hold the xpath list .

What is wrong ? What should I try ? Can lxml help me (Given that the HTML code is broken sometimes)?

Comment: Show `HTML` code of target element

Comment: @Andersson I added the link to HTML code of the target page .

Comment: You could do an interactive Selenium scrapping for the problematic object, and export the code to Python. It should point you at what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to provided link you can match required element with following `XPath`:

```
//span[@class="term-price"]
```

If your element generated with `JavaScript` you need to wait some time for element appearance:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='term-price']")))
```

Comment: Thank's, but why other xpaths won't work ? They should be correct, right ? I have a large list of xpaths and it would take too much time to remake it .

Comment: Your `XPath`es are absolute. It means that they are fixed and sensitive to changes in `DOM`. `DOM` is not constant: it could be changed by some events or `JavaScript` execution. You should find relative `XPath` that will match all your cases without strong binding with `DOM`

Comment: But my price elemnts are generated through JS, will that affect the xpath ?